# Antd responsive Input does work when screen size is "xs"

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, antd

I'm using react + Antd. I'm trying to make my input field the same size no matter how large is the screen.

Everything works fine when the screen size is "sm" (>= 576px).
[image]

However, it will automatically change to this when the screen size is "xs"(<576px). Even though I set `labelCol = {{span: 12}} wrapperCol={{span:12}}`, The label and input field are not at the same line and the width of input is definitely not 12 in this case.
[image]

This is my code, I'm not sure if this is a bug in antd or my understanding to breakpoint is wrong.

```
    <Row>
      <Col sm={{span: 12, offset: 6}}>
        <ProFormText 
          name="name" 
          label="Username" 
          labelCol={{span: 12}}
          wrapperCol={{span: 12}}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
```

Because the [responsive design in antd follows bootstrap 4](https://ant.design/components/grid#:%7E:text=The%20breakpoints%20of%20responsive%20grid%20follow%20BootStrap%204%20media%20queries%20rules%20(not%20including%20occasionally%20part).), I also tagged "bootstrap 4"

**[EDIT]**
CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-8-4-forked-6sntlk?file=/demo.tsx

This is when the size of screen is "md"
[image]
This is what will happen when the screen size changes to "sm:
[image]

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox?

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique Hi, the sandbox has been created, thanks~

Comment: Pass `{{ span: 8, flex: '33%' }}` in labelCol and `wrapperCol`. Label and input field will be placed at same line. On `xs` breakpoint, label and wrapper span are ignored and it looks like a bug. You can create an issue in antd github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in antd, it had been solved https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/44386